# How to make parts of Protractor wait or become synchronous?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, mocha.js

I have code like this in a protractor test, it goes to a home page determines we need to login and then calls this function. Note I'm running this in a NODE.js environment:

```
function Login() {
    browser.findElement(by.id('ID')).then(function (ele) {
        ele.sendKeys('SomeUserName');
        browser.findElement(by.id('password')).then(function (ele) {
            ele.sendKeys('SomePassword');
            browser.findElement(by.partialButtonText('Sign in')).then(function (ele) {
                ele.click();
                browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                    expect(url).toBe("http://NextURLAfterClick");
                    debugger;
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But I can't get the click to fire prior to validating the `browser.getCurrentUrl()`, so what's happening is I'm getting the url of the login page, *I want to get the url after the click to login*.

I suspect it's my misunderstanding of how the Asynchronous nature of this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make parts of Protractor wait or become synchronous?

You can wait for the url to change with the help of [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait):

```
var urlChanged = function(url) {
  return function () {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
      return url === actualUrl;
    });
  };
};

element(by.id('ID')).sendKeys('SomeUserName');
element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('SomePassword');
element(by.partialButtonText('Sign in')).click();

browser.wait(urlChanged("http://NextURLAfterClick")), 5000);
```

where `urlChanged`, in `selenium` terms, is a "Custom Expected Condition".